# unable to add property to the json object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to add status to a response on successful update but I am not able to add the status property to json object of form. Here is my code

```
apiRouter.post('/forms/update', function(req, res){

    if(req.body.id !== 'undefined' && req.body.id){

        var condition = {'_id':req.body.id};

        Form.findOneAndUpdate(condition, req.body, {upsert:true}, function(err, form){

            if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });

            var objForm = form;

            objForm.status = "saved successfully";

            return res.send(objForm);

        });

    }else{
        res.send("Requires form id");
    }

});
```

and here is the response that I get, notice status is missing

```
{
    "_id": "5580ab2045d6866f0e95da5f",
    "test": "myname",
    "data": "{\"name\":3321112,\"sdfsd\"344}",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5580ab2045d6866f0e95da5f"
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to [`.toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) the form:

```
Form.findOneAndUpdate(condition, req.body, {upsert:true}, function(err, form){

    if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });

    var objForm = form.toObject();

    objForm.status = "saved successfully";

    return res.send(objForm);

});
```

Comment: It is valuable to understand (as in the answer of @Jose Mato) that mongoose query results are not extensible!

Answer (score 8):

Mongoose query result are not extensible (object are frozen or sealed), so you can't add more properties. To avoid that, you need to create a copy of the object and manipulate it:

```
var objectForm = Object.create(form);
objectForm.status = 'ok';
```

Update: My answer is old and worked fine, but i will put the same using ES6 syntax

`const objectForm = Object.create({}, form, { status: 'ok' });`

Another way using spread operator:

`const objectForm = { ...form, status: 'ok' }`

Comment: in ES6 another possibility is: const objectForm = Object.assign(form, { status: 'ok' });

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `res.send(objForm)` to `res.send(JSON.stringify(objForm))`. My suspicion is that the the Mongoose model has a custom toJson function so that when you are returning it, it is transforming the response in some way.

Hopefully the above helps.

Comment: no I had tried that as well. It just changes the object to string and does not add the property :(

Comment: A lazy hack then would be to go `var objForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form));` or Object.create as posted above. So that you are working on a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Create empty object and add all properties to it:

```
const data = {};
data._id = yourObject._id; // etc
data.status = "whatever";
return res.send(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a container.

```
array = {};
Model.findOneAndUpdate(condition, function(err, docs){
    array = docs;
    array[0].someField ="Other";
});
```